# Step Functions: Passing in json to RequestBody to API Gateway via POST method

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

so I have a json that is being received by another API Gateway that is invoked.

I want to pass this json in another Task that invokes another API Gateway. I tried to include it in the `RequestBody` via the `$` identifier but it literally sends this without the JSON. Attempting to add `ResultPath` or `InputPath` on this Task throws error.

```
{
  "ApiEndpoint": "fasdffasd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
  "Method": "POST",
  "Headers": {
    "Content-Type": [
      "application/json"
    ]
  },
  "Stage": "uat",
  "Path": "/v1/order/create",
  "RequestBody": {
    "Payload": "$" <---the JSON received by this Task from the previous Task
  },
  "AuthType": "IAM_ROLE"
}
```

The issue is checking CloudWatch Logs I can see that literally the dollar sign as a string is returned. I expected a JSON object.

Comment: Try Payload.$ in the key - I think step function requires $ both in key and value to understand that it should interpolate something.

Comment: @luk2302 tried it but it doesn't seem to find it.  `The JSONPath '$.RequestBody' specified for the field 'Payload.$' could not be found in the input `

Comment: Why are you using `$.RequestBody`, just `$` was correct: `"Payload.$": "$"`.